# How to take control of mousewheel scroll before it happens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse

I'm trying to get the event for a mousewheel scroll right before it happens so that I can stop the scroll and do some stuff and then give back control to the user.

Currently I have the following code to cancel out the scroll. However the scroll happens once and then control is taken away from the user. I'd like to make sure the scroll does not happen, do some other stuff instead, and then give control back afterwards.

```
$('body').on({ 'mousewheel': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Does changing your code to `$('body').on('mousewheel',  function(e) { ... }); ` change the behavior? Note that I have removed the `{}`.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the onwheel event.

`window.onwheel = function(){ 
    alert('your magic here'); 
    return false; 
}`

Comment: How do you undo the event?

Comment: window.onwheel = null;

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to debug and see if the event is being fired in the first scroll?

Is your code inside a `$(document).ready(` function?

If you are using jquery-mousewheel plug-in, you will be able to call this only if you are attaching it after the plug-in is ready and declared before your script (might be on your page header).